# Questions with passing parameters

Tags: c++, arrays

This code is using a Typedef array to return values form functions.

```
// This program will read in a group of test scores (positive integers from 1 to 100)
// from the keyboard and then calculate and output the average score
// as well as the highest and lowest score. There will be a maximum of 100 scores.

// Najah Johnson

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int GradeType[100];             // declares a new data type:
                                                            // an integer array of 100 elements

float findAverage(const GradeType, int);        // finds average of all grades
int  findHighest(const GradeType, int);         // finds highest of all grades
int  findLowest(const GradeType, int);          // finds lowest of all grades

int main()
{
    GradeType grades;       // the array holding the grades.
    int numberOfGrades;     // the number of grades read.
    int pos;                        // index to the array.
    float avgOfGrades;      // contains the average of the grades.
    int highestGrade;       // contains the highest grade.
    int lowestGrade;        // contains the lowest grade.


    // Read in the values into the array

    pos = 0;
    cout << "Please input a grade from 1 to 100, (or -99 to stop)" << endl;
    cin >>  grades[pos];

    while (grades[pos] != -99)
    {
            grades[pos] = 
            pos ++;

            cout << "The total number of grades entered is: " << grades[pos] << endl;


            // Fill in the code to read the grades
    }




    numberOfGrades = pos;   // Fill blank with appropriate identifier

    // call to the function to find average
    avgOfGrades = findAverage(grades, numberOfGrades);

    cout << endl << "The average of all the grades is " << avgOfGrades << endl;


   highestGrade = findHighest(GradeType, size);
    // Fill in the call to the function that calculates highest grade

    cout << endl << "The highest grade is " << highestGrade << endl;


  lowestGrade = findLowest(GradeType, size);

 cout << endl << "The lowest grade is " << lowestGrade << endl;
    // Fill in the call to the function that calculates lowest grade
    // Fill in code to write the lowest to the screen

    return 0;
}

//********************************************************************************
// findAverage
//
// task:              This function receives an array of integers and its size.
//                    It finds and returns the average of the numbers in the array
// data in:           array of floating point numbers
// data returned: average of the numbers in the array
//
//********************************************************************************

float findAverage(const GradeType array, int size)
{
    float sum = 0;                  // holds the sum of all the numbers

    for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++)
            sum = sum + array[pos];

    return (sum / size);    // returns the average
}

//****************************************************************************
// findHighest
//
// task:              This function receives an array of integers and its size.
//                    It finds and returns the highest value of the numbers in
//                the array
// data in:           array of floating point numbers
// data returned: highest value of the numbers in the array
//
//****************************************************************************

int findHighest(const GradeType array, int size)
{
int highest;

highest = array[0];

 for(int count = 0; count < size; count++)
 {
     if(array[count] > highest)
         highest = array[count];



 }
    return highest;
    // Fill in the code for this function
}

//****************************************************************************
// findLowest
//
// task:              This function receives an array of integers and its size.
//                    It finds and returns the lowest value of the numbers in
//                the array
// data in:           array of floating point numbers
// data returned: lowest value of the numbers in the array
//
//****************************************************************************

int findLowest(const GradeType array, int size)
{
int lowest;

lowest = array[0];      

 for (int count = 1; count < size; count++)
   {
       if (array[count] < lowest)
       lowest = array[count];


   }

    return lowest;

    // Fill in the code for this function
}
```

This is an updated version of the code form my deleted question so that everyone can get the full gist. These are the three issues that I have with my code:

```
#main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
#main.cpp:55:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
    highestGrade = findHighest(GradeType, size);
                                        ^
#main.cpp:55:46: error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope
    highestGrade = findHighest(GradeType, size);
                                          ^~~~
#main.cpp:61:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
   lowestGrade = findLowest(GradeType, size);
                                     ^
```

As you can see they all have to do with the parameters of my function calls. The program is C++ in case anybody was wondering.

Comment: Instead of type specifiers like  GradeType you have to supply objects as for example grades to function calls.

Comment: `typedef int GradeType[100];             // declares a new data type:` - No. The comment is *wrong*. `typedef` (as well as `using`) does *not* define a new type, merely an alias for an existing type. Also, that's a *very strange* `typedef`.

Comment: Entering the supply object grades knocked out two of the errors. But the error that says that int 'size' isn't declared within the scope is still there. Which doesn't make since to me because the code in both the findAverage and findLowest functions seem to utilize it just fine.

Comment: I managed to find the answer. Turns out that you can also use the numberOfGrades as your parameter again.